# How to start multiple faust app in the same time?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, faust

I'm new user of Faust and don't know how to fix the problem when I ran 3 faust apps in the same time. Specifically:

I have 3 python file, In each, I run 1 service for listening from kafka server. Each file contains code as below, the different in each file is just the TOPIC_INPUT name.

```
app = faust.App(
    'UserInfoReceive',
    broker= 'kafka://' + SERVER_INPUT + f':{DVWAP_KAFKA_PORT}',
    value_serializer='raw',
)

kafka_topic = app.topic(TOPIC_INPUT)

@app.agent(kafka_topic)
async def userSettingInput(streamInput):
    async for msg in streamInput:
        userResgister(msg)
```

### Expected behavior

Expect 3 python files can run normally and listen to the comming kafka event

### Actual behavior

it generates OSError as this img

Hi all,

I'm new user of Faust and don't know how to fix the problem when I ran 3 faust apps in the same time. Specifically:

I have 3 python file, In each, I run 1 service for listening from kafka server. Each file contains code as below, the only difference in each file is the TOPIC_INPUT name.
app = faust.App(
'UserInfoReceive',
broker= 'kafka://' + SERVER_INPUT + f':{DVWAP_KAFKA_PORT}',
value_serializer='raw',
)

kafka_topic = app.topic(TOPIC_INPUT)

@app.agent(kafka_topic)
async def userSettingInput(streamInput):
async for msg in streamInput:
userResgister(msg)
Expected behavior
Expect 3 python files can run normally and listen to the comming kafka event

Actual behavior
it generates OSError as this img

[image]

### Versions

Python version: 3.9
Faust version 1.10.4
Operating system WSL Linux Subsystem on Windows
Kafka version kafka-python==1.4.7

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because each faust worker by default uses the same web_port (6066). You can change this configuration for each additional app instance when you configure it.

```
app = faust.App(
    'UserInfoReceive',
    broker= 'kafka://' + SERVER_INPUT + f':{DVWAP_KAFKA_PORT}',
    value_serializer='raw',
    web_port=7001 #<- ADD DIFFERENT WEB PORT HERE
)
```